# Android: record video with "continuous" auto-focus

Tags: android, video, crash, recording, autofocus

I work on video recording; everything works except for requesting continuous focus. This is what I do (tried both in surfaceCreated and surfaceChanged with no success):

```
camera = Camera.open();
camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
```

then I do either

```
parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
```

or

```
parameters.set("focus-mode", "continuous-video");
```

both should do the same thing; then I set parameters with

```
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

This last line always crashes! So do I miss something?

By the way, I test on rather new devices like Desire HD, Galaxy S, Galaxy Tab 7 and 10.1, which must have support for continuous auto-focus; at least their built-in camera apps support it.

Comment: What is displayed in error log?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, ingsaurabh. This is the (mostly meaningless crash report):
`java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1062)
     at com.mr.RecorderScreen.surfaceCreated(RecorderScreen.java:76)`

Comment: Has anybody managed **to record video with auto-focus** in Android at all? If so, please post some overview on what should be done here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have sort of solution to this problem: I was able to manually focus camera calling Camera#autoFocus(...).

This still has serious issues. First, calling autofocus while shooting video is not working on some Samsung devices. Also it's not a good idea to force your users to manually focus the camera during video recording.

So if you were able to **normally** focus your videos while recording - your advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You should check if Continuous Auto Focus is supported by the device. This is something that works for me, please give it a try.

```
boolean startContinuousAutoFocus() {

    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();

    String CAF_PICTURE = Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE, 
           CAF_VIDEO = Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO, 
           supportedMode = focusModes
                   .contains(CAF_PICTURE) ? CAF_PICTURE : focusModes
                   .contains(CAF_VIDEO) ? CAF_VIDEO : "";

    if (!supportedMode.equals("")) {

        params.setFocusMode(supportedMode);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried similar code, but the problem is continuous focus is not supported on those devices.